# Primefaces row edit listener wont work

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces

I use Primefaces 3.5.jar and Hibernate. 
I have problem with datatable row edit listener. When i debug project i can enter in onCancel method but onEdit never start. My XHTML code:

```
    <f:facet name="header">  
        Workhours
    </f:facet>  

    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{workhoursBean.onEdit}" update=":form:messages" />  
    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{workhoursBean.onCancel}" update=":form:messages" />  



    <p:column headerText="Start" style="width:20%">  
        <p:cellEditor>  
            <f:facet name="output">  
                <h:outputText value="#{workhours.workStart}" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="input">  
                <p:inputText value="#{workhours.workStart}" style="width:100%" label="Year"/>  
            </f:facet>  
        </p:cellEditor>  
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="End" style="width:20%">  
        <p:cellEditor>  
            <f:facet name="output">  
                <h:outputText value="#{workhours.workEnd}" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="input">  
                <p:inputText value="#{workhours.workEnd}" style="width:100%" label="Year"/>  
            </f:facet>  
        </p:cellEditor>  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column style="width:6%">  
        <p:rowEditor />  
    </p:column>  

</p:dataTable>
```

And my Bean method:

```
  public void onCancel(RowEditEvent event) {  
    //do stuff
}
 public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {  
    Object oldValue = event.getObject();  
    Object newValue = event.getObject();
    if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {  
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    }
}
```

Have anyone idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Well i guess you're trying to put a date in your edit field. If you look at your response in firebug you will see an error like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<partial-response>
  <error>
    <error-name>
    javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException</error-name>
    <error-message>
      <![CDATA[org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareELException: javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert Tue May 21 17:44:32 CEST 2010 of type class java.lang.String to class java.util.Date]]>
</error-message>
  </error>
</partial-response>
```

So it breaks. You can solve this by using f:convertDateTime

Try this:

```
<f:facet name="input">
  <p:inputText value="#{workhours.workEnd}" style="width:100%"
  label="Year">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
  </p:inputText>
</f:facet>
```

Also do this for your workStart and your editing wil work.

Answer (score 0):

You condition  !newValue.equals(oldValue))  will never return true because oldValue and newValue are the same object